# Reading data from Excel in Haskell

Tags: excel, haskell, com, automation

I would like to get data from .xls files without manually opening Excel. 
One possibility is to use COM automation.

There are the [com-1.2.3](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/com-1.2.3) and [hdirect](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hdirect) packages, but I can't find any examples of how to use these packages with Excel.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With something like this, if your needs are relatively simple, I've found that it's more straightforward to find/write a command line executable that just pulls out a csv from the xls file. Then you invoke that executable from haskell, and proceed with its output from there.

Comment: I agree for small task with only one sheet. But sometimes i have data shared out among several sheets. My current solution is to write a excel vbscript. But i would like now to use only an haskell exe rather than use several applications.

Comment: What I'm suggesting is a single-purpose executable that just dumps a given sheet from a given excel file (both specified on the cmd line). Then you can wrap that up in a single haskell call that given an excel file and a sheet returns all the parsed data. So it's like using com automation except going through the indirection of an additional executable. The only advantage being how much simpler this is to do. The only disadvantage being that you now need two executables instead of one (but you still only need to execute the one directly).

Comment: Thanks. With your suggestion i found some cmd line like [http://www.softinterface.com/Convert-XLS/Features/Convert-XLS-To-CSV.htm] to deal with and that is giving me other paths to explore. But my question is more on the understanding of the COM package. the example provided at [http://haskell.forkio.com/com-examples] is not sufficient enougth to use it with excel or word. So if someone have an excel snippet to share that could be interesting to dig into.

Answer (score 3):

In Ruby, I use rjb (ruby java bridge) and use a library from Java for excel (e.g. JExcelAPI as explained in http://www.slideshare.net/weyus/rjb).

It seems that there are some Java bridges for Haskell? http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Applications_and_libraries/Interfacing_other_languages#Java
Though I have no experience with them...

I wonder whether that's the best solution...

Answer (score 2):

Now there is also [xlsx](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xlsx) on Hackage (for the Office Open XML xlsx format), although I haven't yet tried it myself.